# OpenGLES -[EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:] crash in iOS9 (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, sprite-kit, ios9

I am having a lot of Sprite Kit crashes in iOS 9. The below are logs I am getting. I don't think this has anything to do with my code and seems more like a SpriteKit bug in iOS 9. Anyone else faced the same issue and resolved yet?

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libmetal_timestamp.dylib       0x2ca73322 (Missing)
1  libmetal_timestamp.dylib       0x2ca73e13 (Missing)
2  RawCamera                      0x226b068d (Missing)
3  OpenAL                         0x2685a17f (Missing)
4  OpenAL                         0x2685a0b3 (Missing)
5  OpenGLES                       0x26865079 -[EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:] + 60
6  Jet                            0x2dc85eb7 jet_context_OpenGL::present(std::__1::shared_ptr<jet_texture> const&, double) + 290
7  SpriteKit                      0x280ec63d SKCRenderer::render(SKCNode*, float vector[4], std::__1::shared_ptr<jet_framebuffer> const&, unsigned int vector[4], matrix_float4x4, bool, NSDictionary*, SKCStats*, SKCStats*) + 1644
8  SpriteKit                      0x28089a7f __51-[SKView _vsyncRenderForTime:preRender:postRender:]_block_invoke + 998
9  SpriteKit                      0x28089d59 __51-[SKView _vsyncRenderForTime:preRender:postRender:]_block_invoke196 + 300
10 SpriteKit                      0x280895e1 -[SKView _vsyncRenderForTime:preRender:postRender:] + 440
11 SpriteKit                      0x2808b15b __29-[SKView setUpRenderCallback]_block_invoke + 118
12 SpriteKit                      0x280bc1fb -[SKDisplayLink _callbackForNextFrame:] + 58
13 QuartzCore                     0x27afe85f CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 106
14 QuartzCore                     0x27afe6af CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 594
15 IOMobileFramebuffer            0x2db8b58b IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 86
16 IOKit                          0x25179345 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 256
17 CoreFoundation                 0x2406ab59 __CFMachPortPerform + 132
18 CoreFoundation                 0x2407cf7b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
19 CoreFoundation                 0x2407c68f __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342
20 CoreFoundation                 0x2407aaa1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1704
21 CoreFoundation                 0x23fcd0d9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
22 CoreFoundation                 0x23fccecd CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
23 GraphicsServices               0x2d342af9 GSEventRunModal + 160
24 UIKit                          0x282562dd UIApplicationMain + 144
25 jumpytiles                     0x9358c main (AppDelegate.swift:17)
26 libdyld.dylib                  0x35ec8873 start + 2
```